# Why first "display: inline-block;" div below that the second?

Tags: html, css

Why first "display: inline-block;" div below that the second ?
I want two div in one line.

see example http://jsfiddle.net/ubo2bok9/

**CSS code**

```
.conteiner { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px; 
    width:  200px; 
    background-color: #2e9;
    margin: 2px;
}

.inConteiner {
    width:  190px; 
    height: 30px;

    background-color: #29e;
    color: white;

    margin: 2px;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="conteiner">
    first 
</div>

<div class="conteiner" id="BaseConteiner">
    second
    <div class="inConteiner">
      <p> 111111111111111 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inConteiner">
      <p> 222222222222222 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inConteiner">
      <p> 333333333333333 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set `vertical-align:middle;` to your `.conteiner` element because the text is being aligned with the elements in another container.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbtpgz9b/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a property `float:left` to your `.conteiner`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ubo2bok9/1/)**

```
.conteiner { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px; 
    width:  200px; 
    background-color: #2e9;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Floating might cause problem if he didn't clear it afterwards. I think setting `vertical-align` is better.

Comment: @Billy Depends on his requirements. Well even that's possible!

Answer (score 0):

you could use like this

```
.conteiner { 
    display: table-cell;
    height: 300px; 
    width:  200px; 
    background-color: #2e9;
    margin: 2px;
    float:left;
}
```

for fixed width just use table-cell it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add `vertical-align:top;` in `.conteiner` div

```
.conteiner { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px; 
    width:  200px; 
    background-color: #2e9;
    margin: 2px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubo2bok9/3/)